# Proof of Graph Subdivision

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing, planar-graphs

Prove that every simple graph of order $n ≥ 4$ and size at least $2n − 2$ contains a subdivision of $K_4$.

Answer (score 0):

This is Exercise 8.3.1 page 132 of Bondy's book "Graph Theory with Applications". There is a hint for this exercise on page 238  of the same book.